# POSIX Threads with Map Reduce

Tags: c, mapreduce, pthreads

I was recently given an assignment in my Operating Systems class that explains we must use Map() and Reduce() functions [in C] to sort and count the frequency of words in a text file.  This is a rather arbitrary and simplistic example as I have seen through a bit of research, but what I am having difficulty understanding is the requirement of using POSIX threads in the program.  Does this mean that the pseudocode algorithms for Map() and Reduce() functions that are floating around do not inherently use pthreads or multiple Linux processes? Such as...

```
function map(String name, String document):
  // name: document name
  // document: document contents
  for each word w in document:
    emit (w, 1)

function reduce(String word, Iterator partialCounts):
  // word: a word
  // partialCounts: a list of aggregated partial counts
  sum = 0
  for each pc in partialCounts:
    sum += pc
  emit (word, sum)
```

I have tried to find this answer elsewhere, but with no luck; any advice is appreciated!

(I am not looking for the code to the project, just a better explanation)

Comment: As a simple example, imagine you have 100 documents. Then the `map` function needs to be called 100 times. Those calls can be executed serially on a single processor, or run in parallel on a multicore processor, or even dispatched to 100 remote computers. Your task is to make sure that the 100 calls to `map` are executed as fast as possible, given the available computational resources.

Comment: So then calling the map in an interative loop (such as a while loop) would be running it in a serial manner, opposed to initializing a pthread to run alongside and map many times at once

Comment: Yup, that's right.

Comment: Guess another question I have would be how exactly would pthreads be used to implement the map method so efficiently?

Comment: If it is line by line with ONE text document, then I am assuming each thread such be passed a line.

Comment: I see. I reread the question and you did mention that you're trying to use MapReduce on a single text file. So in that case, I would break the file into approximately equal chunks, and then give each worker one chunk to chew on.

Comment: Typically, on production systems, the workers are standalone VMs. So, for example, if you had 100 VMs, you could work on 100 chunks in paralell. With only one 4-core machine, you could use 4 worker threads instead.